# Byte swapping functions

Tags: c, array

I recently programmed some byte swapping functions. As a special I did a function which can convert an entire int array. I please you to look at the following aspects:

- portability
- performance
- usability
- efficiency

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint16_t _bswap16(uint16_t a)
{
  a = ((a & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((a & 0xFF00) >> 8);
  return a;
}

uint32_t _bswap32(uint32_t a)
{
  a = ((a & 0x000000FF) << 24) |
      ((a & 0x0000FF00) <<  8) |
      ((a & 0x00FF0000) >>  8) |
      ((a & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
  return a;
}

uint64_t _bswap64(uint64_t a)
{
  a = ((a & 0x00000000000000FFULL) << 56) | 
      ((a & 0x000000000000FF00ULL) << 40) | 
      ((a & 0x0000000000FF0000ULL) << 24) | 
      ((a & 0x00000000FF000000ULL) <<  8) | 
      ((a & 0x000000FF00000000ULL) >>  8) | 
      ((a & 0x0000FF0000000000ULL) >> 24) | 
      ((a & 0x00FF000000000000ULL) >> 40) | 
      ((a & 0xFF00000000000000ULL) >> 56);
  return a;
}
```

Byte Swapping functions for arrays:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void *_bswap_a(void *restrict const array, size_t const elem_size, size_t const ndimensions, size_t const *restrict const dimensions, bool const copy, void (*bswapfcn)(void *))
{
    /* Validate arguments */
    if (array == NULL || elem_size <= 1 || ndimensions == 0 || dimensions == NULL || bswapfcn == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    {
        size_t array_size       = elem_size;
        size_t i                = 0;
        unsigned char *a        = array;
        // I know, this is only needed for copy=true....
        unsigned char *elemval  = malloc(elem_size);

        if (!elemval) return NULL;

        /* Caluclate array size */
        for (i = 0; i < ndimensions; ++i) {
            array_size *= dimensions[i];
        }

        /* Copy the array ? */
        if (copy) {
            a = malloc(array_size);

            if (!a) {
                free(elemval);

                return NULL;
            }
        }

        /* Go through each element */
        for (i = 0; i < array_size; i += elem_size) {
            /* Pointer to element */
            void *element   = (((unsigned char *)array) + i);

            if (copy) {
                memcpy(elemval, element, elem_size);

                bswapfcn(elemval);

                memcpy(a + i, elemval, elem_size);
            } else {
                // Swap the bytes
                bswapfcn(element);
            }
        }

        free(elemval);

        return a;
    }
}


void _bswap16f(void *el)
{
    uint16_t    *ptr    = el;
    uint16_t    val     = *ptr;

    *ptr = _bswap16(val);
}

uint16_t *_bswap16a(uint16_t *restrict a, size_t const ndimensions, size_t *restrict const dimensions, bool const copy)
{
    return _bswap_a(a, sizeof(uint16_t), ndimensions, dimensions, copy, _bswap16f);
}

void _bswap32f(void *el)
{
    uint32_t    *ptr    = el;
    uint32_t    val     = *ptr;

    *ptr = _bswap32(val);
}

uint32_t *_bswap32a(uint32_t *restrict const a, size_t const ndimensions, size_t *restrict const dimensions, bool const copy)
{
    return _bswap_a(a, sizeof(uint32_t), ndimensions, dimensions, copy, _bswap32f);
}

void _bswap64f(void *el)
{
    uint64_t    *ptr    = el;
    uint64_t    val     = *ptr;

    *ptr = _bswap64(val);
}

uint32_t *_bswap64a(uint64_t *restrict const a, size_t const ndimensions, size_t *restrict const dimensions, bool const copy)
{
    return _bswap_a(a, sizeof(uint64_t), ndimensions, dimensions, copy, _bswap64f);
}
```

Usage:

```c
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    /* Swap 32bit Integer */
    uint32_t _swappedInteger            = _bswap32(32);
    /* Swap 32bit Integer array (2 dimensional) and copy the array */
    uint32_t _2darray[2][4]             = {{8, 7, 6, 5}, {4, 3, 2, 1}};
    size_t dimensions[2]                = {2, 4};
    uint32_t (*_swappedArray)[4]        = (void *)_bswap32a((void *)_2darray, 2, dimensions, true);

    fprintf(stderr, "%-12u:%4u \n", _swappedInteger, _bswap32(_swappedInteger));
    fprintf(stderr, "%-12u:%4u \n", _swappedArray[1][2], _bswap32(_swappedArray[1][2]));

    /* _swappedArray is a copy of _2darray so we need to free it */
    free(_swappedArray);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Regarding performance: Well this will reduce portability but [MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3140177.aspx), [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and clang (same as gcc I think) all have intrinsics defined for `bswap` which will probably perform better than your implementations. At least on x86 they'll probably make use of the [`bswap`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_21.html) instruction. So you might want to have a few `#ifdef`'ed alternatives for different compilers.
2. You are allocating memory which is only needed for a specific code path so maybe you should just not allocate it if `copy == false`. You can set `elemVal = NULL` and still unconditionally call `free` on it as `free(NULL)` is perfectly legal.
3. Your naming is a bit terse. `bswap` itself is ok as it's a reasonably known operation but what the heck is `_bswap_a` and `_bswapf` (it's also inconsistent `_a` vs `f`)? Please prefer more explanatory names like `_bswap_array` and `_bswap_field`.
4. I find code like this confusing to read (the pointer alias is confusing to me):

   > ```
   >    void _bswap16f(void *el)
   > {
   >     uint16_t    *ptr    = el;
   >     uint16_t    val     = *ptr;
   >     *ptr = _bswap16(val);
   > }
   > ```

   at least I would use less terse names:

   ```
   void _bswap16_field(void *field)
   {
        uint16_t value = *(uint16_t *)field;
        *field = _bswap16(value);
   }
   ```

   Don't have a C compiler handy but you might be able to make that `void *` a `uint16_t *` and still have it all work (saves you a cast).

Answer (score 3):

What's with all the underscores? Names starting `_` are very unpleasant to use in client code. This naming convention is usually associated with library internals. And even so, doesn't seem very necessary.

---

You could very well return directly instead of assigning the result to a variable:

```
return ((a & 0x00FF) << 8) | ((a & 0xFF00) >> 8);
```

---

That local scope inside `_bswap_a` is unusual and seems unnecessary:

```
{
    size_t array_size       = elem_size;
    size_t i                = 0;
    ....
}
```

---

Other functions that take pointers, like `_bswap16f` and `_bswap32f`, are not validating the inputs before dereferencing them. You should at least `assert` that the pointers are not null.

Comment: You are right, in client code underscores looks bad. I forgot you tell that I'm using this as a library internal. Therefore no checking in functions `_bswap16f`, `_bswap32f`.

Comment: @d3l, even though the functions are only used internally, an `assert` check is still advisable to help the detection of errors during development. Remember that it will be disabled on production, so performance shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 3):

See no value in making constants `unsigned long long`, but see future down-sides.  If `unsigned long long` has a wider range than `uint64_t`, the following promotes the `a & 0x00000000000000FFULL` operation to one that is `unsigned long long`, an unnecessary expansion.  OTOH an optimizing compiler may cope with that unnecessary widening.  Suggest instead to only append the `u` suffix to insure constants are some unsigned type without making them extra wide.

```
uint64_t _bswap64(uint64_t a) {
  // a = ((a & 0x00000000000000FFULL) << 56) | 
  //    ((a & 0x000000000000FF00ULL) << 40) |  ...

  a = ((a & 0x00000000000000FFu) << 56) | 
      ((a & 0x000000000000FF00u) << 40) |   ...
      ...
```

Curious why suffixes were added in `_bswap64()`, but not `_bswap32()`.  Suggest appending the `u` suffix.

```
uint32_t _bswap32(uint32_t a) {
  // a = ((a & 0x000000FF) << 24) |
  //    ((a & 0x0000FF00) <<  8) |  ...

  a = ((a & 0x000000FFu) << 24) |
      ((a & 0x0000FF00u) <<  8) |  ...
```